# How to set the filter condition by default for specific condition in view

Tags: views

How to set the filter condition by default for specific condition in view i,e i have view with the filter condition STATUS drop down list has 1]live 2] discard,so here i want to filter by default for live status when i open this view can any please tell me how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please edit the question a bit and clarify what you want in "In other words" section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group filters, that way it will allow you to set a default.

[image]